# Selecting 2 named ranges from excel in a OleDBCommand

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Here is my code as of now:

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Id, Number", cn);
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
while( reader.Read() )
{
    results.Add((int)reader["Id"], (int)reader["Number"]);
}
```

Id and Number are named ranges in my excel file. I am attempting to return a `dictionary<int, int>` with the results of this query.

The issue is that the line `reader["Id"]` is throwing an exception. When I debug the result set I can see that it has the correct value for Id. Am I retrieving the data incorrectly?

**Bonus:** I also need to only return rows where Number is not null. I was hoping I could just add `where Number is not null` to the OldDbCommand, but that also threw an exception.

Is that anything you guys can see that I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Not certain about this so I won't post it as an answer, but the direct cast of  reader["Id"] to an int I think may be the problem. I think you might want to get its Value property before casting it.

Comment: @DavidW That is a good point. That is one thing I have not tried and will test it out tomorrow. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

David W's comment was correct. I was unable to cast in that same line. Also, calling `reader["Id"]` was not working. Replaced with `Reader[0]` and everything works great.

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from Number, Id", cn);
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

while( reader.Read() )
{
   var Number= reader[0];
   var Id = reader[1];

   if(Id == DBNull.Value || WoNumber == DBNull.Value)
   {
       break;
   }

   results.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Id), Convert.ToInt32(Number));
}
```